"Mandatory reservation" on Off-Peak ticket?
I have booked Super Off-Peak tickets from London to Bath and back. My understanding is that this ticket allows me to travel on any train (peak restrictions not being applicable on weekends). However, I decided to reserve seats on the trains we're most likely to take since the train may be busy.
The reservations I got have "Mandatory Reservation" printed on them. Does this mean I am now restricted to travel on the reserved train?
(Sorry for the amateurish removal of identifying info!)



You have a super off-peak ticket, which means you are only tied to the date of travel and the peak hour rules.
I do not know why the ticket came with a mandatory reservation title, but you are absolutely free to abandon it, your ticket, as a walk-up ticket (not Advance) is not tied to it.
You can take any train (minding the routing restriction) on that day

As a rule, there are no mandatory reservation services (apart from sleepers) in the UK for such walk-up tickets. There will always be unreserved seating either along the train or on a specific coach.
Only Advance tickets are bound to a particular train, so a reservation is required.
That assumption is wrongly carried by the train operating companies who (wrongly) set that flag as such and/or the retailer carries that flag down.
National Rail Conditions of Travel C.3

3.2 Some types of Ticket (for instance “advance” Tickets) require you to make a reservation
when buying your Ticket. For other Tickets you can request a reservation either when
buying a Ticket, or before the departure of your train on presentation of a valid Ticket, at
most staffed stations. You are allowed a maximum of one seat reservation per person
for each train that forms part of your journey.


3.3 Unless you have made a reservation, please note that your Ticket does not automatically
entitle you to a seat, and at busy times you may have to stand. You will not be entitled to
any refund in these cases unless you hold a first class Ticket and no first class seats were
available on a train service where the timetable indicated that first class seats would be
provided. More information on the refund to which you are entitled in such circumstances
can be found in Condition 31.

You can further visit the link on the ticket (here nre.co.uk/yu) to find the exact restrictions applied to your ticket

Thanks. I hope ticket inspectors won't have the same "wrong assumption" that either GWR (the operator) or SWR/Waterloo ticket office (the retailer) had!

@user16790133 don't worry, they'll see it's a super off-peak and you'll be fine. Just don't even show them the reservation coupon. Nicolas here is absolutely correct, this is clearly a printing error imho. (Incidentally the part of the answer that deals with mandatory reservations, while true, is irrelevant here as the train in question was marked in the system as not mandatory https://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/service/gb-nr:C63030/2024-06-09/detailed )
